# Scala: Overriding equals for value classes

Tags: scala

To get more type safety in our code base we have started to replace generic Strings, Ints etc. with type safe value classes, but I am struggling to get them working conveniently with the `==` operator and literals. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Our value classes are defined and used like this:

```
case class Name(value: String) extends AnyVal {}
object Name { implicit def to(something:String): Name = Name(something) // convenience }

case class Address(value: String) extends AnyVal {}
object Address { implicit def to(something:String): Address = Address(something) // convenience }

case class Person(name: Name, address: Address) {
  def move(newAddress: Address) = copy(address=newAddress)
}
val somebody = Person("Pete", "Street 1")

somebody.move(Address("Street 2")) // allowed
somebody.move(somebody.name) // not allowed, which is exactly what we want
somebody.move("Street 2") // allowed by convenience
```

Now, I would like them to compare "naturally" on their inner `value`:

```
Name("Pete") == "Pete" // should be true, but evaluates to False
```

I can sort of fix this by overriding `equals` like this:

```
case class Name(value: String) extends AnyVal {
  override def equals(other: Any) = 
    if (other.isInstanceOf[Name])
      other.asInstanceOf[Name].value == this.value
    else if (other.isInstanceOf[String])
      other == this.value
    else
      false
}

Name("Pete") == "Pete" // now evaluates to true
```

However, this solution is not symmetric:

```
"Pete" == Name("Pete") // evaluates to false, because it is using String.equals
```

I do not know how to fix this. Not even declaring an implicit conversion from Name to String helps (and I would much prefer not to have such a thing). Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

EDIT: I probably failed to be clear on this, but I am not really looking for advice on software development. This is meant to be a technical question: Can it be done in Scala or not?

I have some reasons for doing what I have described, but sadly they relate to a codebase of tens of thousands of lines of Scala code, and cannot be conveyed in a short stack overflow question.

Comment: Are you sure they should evaluate to true? Isn't the point of value classes, that `"Pete"` and `Name("Pete")` are different entities?

Comment: Your partial solution won't compile for me due to limitations on value classes as [documented here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#summary-of-limitations). (See limitation #4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `==` can be made to work in this situation. What you might do is define a different comparison operation.

```
case class Name(value: String) extends AnyVal {
  def is(n: Name): Boolean = value == n.value
}
```

You'll also have to broaden the scope of the implicit converter so that it can be accessed for these conversions.

```
implicit def toName(something:String): Name = Name(something) // not in object
```

Now this works.

```
val somebody = Person("Pete", "Street 1")
somebody.move(Address("Street 2")) // allowed
somebody.move("Street 2") // allowed by convenience
somebody.name is "Pete"   // true
"Pete" is somebody.name   // true
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you should just get rid of your `convenience` implicits instead. They defeat the purpose:

```
 val john = Person("Street 1", "John") // mixed up order
 john.move("Pete") // Yup, I can "move" to a name ...
```

Now, john is someone named "Street 1", and living at address "Pete". This isn't something that you want to be allowed after going with the trouble of defining all the value classes.